# KeyError: "None of [Index([('g', 'e', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'r', 'y', '_', 'x')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Tags: pandas, geopandas, keyerror

**My code**

```
rpg15_19.loc[rpg15_19.geometry_x != None, 'geom'] = rpg15_19['geometry_x']
rpg15_19.loc[rpg15_19.geometry_y != None, 'geom'] = rpg15_19['geometry_y']
rpg15_19.loc[rpg15_19.geometry != None, 'geom'] = rpg15_19['geometry']`
```

Message error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 2>()
     1 # on créé une seule colonne de géométrie
----> 2 rpg15_19.loc[rpg15_19.geometry_x != None, 'geom'] = rpg15_19['geometry_x']
     3 rpg15_19.loc[rpg15_19.geometry_y != None, 'geom'] = rpg15_19['geometry_y']
     4 rpg15_19.loc[rpg15_19.geometry != None, 'geom'] = rpg15_19['geometry']

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:712, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   710 else:
   711     key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 712 indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
   713 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
   715 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:661, in _LocationIndexer._get_setitem_indexer(self, key)
   659 if isinstance(key, tuple):
   660     with suppress(IndexingError):
--> 661         return self._convert_tuple(key)
   663 if isinstance(key, range):
   664     return list(key)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:799, in _LocationIndexer._convert_tuple(self, key)
   797     self._validate_key_length(key)
   798     for i, k in enumerate(key):
--> 799         idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i)
   800         keyidx.append(idx)
   802 return tuple(keyidx)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1291, in _LocIndexer._convert_to_indexer(self, key, axis)
  1289         return inds
  1290     else:
-> 1291         return self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)[1]
  1292 else:
  1293     try:

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1327, in _LocIndexer._get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
  1324 ax = self.obj._get_axis(axis)
  1325 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1327 keyarr, indexer = ax._get_indexer_strict(key, axis_name)
  1329 return keyarr, indexer

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5782, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
  5779 else:
  5780     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 5782 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  5784 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
  5785 if isinstance(key, Index):
  5786     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5842, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
  5840     if use_interval_msg:
  5841         key = list(key)
-> 5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
  5844 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
  5845 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "None of [Index([('g', 'e', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'r', 'y', '_', 'x'), ('g', 'e', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'r', 'y', '_', 'x')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

I want to create a single column of geometry but I get an error message like this. Can you help me please?

Comment: It looks like you're not using the [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) syntax correctly, but it's hard for us to debug without more information. can you paste the output of `print(rpg15_19)` as a code block and explain more about what you're trying to achieve?